# How to change value of input[type=number] on key press via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I already have a series of events of keypress to trigger some sound, to run countdown clock and whatnot.

I also want to assign keycode to change the value of a couple of `input[type=number]`, either subtract or add value by incremental of -1/+1 each key press. I have done some search but couldn't really give me the ultimate guide.

Here's what I have in the header.

```
function runScript(e){
if(e.keyCode == 32 && e.shiftKey){
   gameclock();
}}
```

and on my html

```
<body onkeydown="runScript(event)"> 
...
<input id="whateverID1" type="number" value="00">
```

Let's say if I want to add `#whateverID1` value by pressing `=` and subtract `#whateverID1` value by pressing `-`, appreciate any guide to how can I achieve that. Thank you very much.

I have tried this but doesn't seem to work.

```
var CounterName = 0; 
if(e.keyCode == 49 ) {
document.getElementById('whateverID1').value = ++CounterName;
} 
if(e.keyCode == 50 ) { 
document.getElementById('whateverID1').value = --CounterName; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, using onclick/onkeydown things in html is usually bad practice. Rather, give the element an id or class and add an eventListener from the JS instead.

Try this below, the jsfiddle is working and should let you do what you want:

```
document.getElementById("bodyId").addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  var CounterName = 1;
  var currentValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('whateverID1').value);

  if(event.keyCode == 187) {
    document.getElementById('whateverID1').value = currentValue + CounterName;
  }
  else if(event.keyCode == 189) { 
    document.getElementById('whateverID1').value = currentValue - CounterName;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Maxmaxs5/7thqo0zs/7/

If this helps or you need anything else, let me know!

Comment: Thanks @kieran-mcwilliamw.  
And quick one here  
`if(event.key == "="  && event.shiftKey )`  will not work for combination key?

Comment: Okay for some reason once you try to do combination key, `key` does not like to work, so `keyCode` is actually better. Try `if(event.keyCode == 187 && event.shiftKey)`. Code for `=` is 187 and for `-` is 189. If you need to find keyCodes for other keys you can look them up or just do `console.log(event.keyCode)`. Character codes and key codes are not the same, which I am sure can trip people up easily. Hope that fixes it, if so let me know!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. But it kill my another function `$('.home input[type=number]').change(function(){
  if(parseInt(this.value) > 4){
   $('#home-b').prop('checked', true);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#home-b').prop('checked', false);
  }
 });` oops

Comment: Erm I'm not sure how those two functions have any correlation/how one killed the other.. And I would need to see more code to help you out again, maybe email me?